# Formatting Array to a new output

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am receiving data from my server and when I output it to the console I get the following structure

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    0:
        Category: "cat1"
        Count: 11
    1: 
        Category: "cat2"
        Count: 14
    2: 
        Category: "cat3"
        Count: 21
```

What I am trying to do is prepare this data for a bar chart.  Google expects my data to be provided in the following format

```
const chartData = [
    ["Category", "Count"],
    ["cat1", 11]
    ["cat2", 14]
    ["cat3", 21]
]
```

So the first row should be the keys, in this case Category and Count.  Then each following row should contain the values for Category and Count.

I got a bit confused at first and with some help, came up with the following

```js
const chartData = {
  chartOne: [{
      Category: "cat1",
      Count: 11
    },
    {
      Category: "cat2",
      Count: 14
    },
    {
      Category: "cat3",
      Count: 21
    }
  ]
}

const newChartData = chartData.chartOne.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[0].push(item.Category);
  acc[1].push(item.Count);
  return acc;
}, [[],[]]);

console.log(newChartData);
```

You can see from the output that the above puts the values for Category in row one, instead of the keys.  So how can I achieve the output I am after whereby the keys are row one, and the values for those respective keys are in the following rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by having a nested accumulator array with category and count

```js
const chartData = {
  chartOne: [{
      Category: "cat1",
      Count: 11
    },
    {
      Category: "cat2",
      Count: 14
    },
    {
      Category: "cat3",
      Count: 21
    }
  ]
}

const newChartData = chartData.chartOne.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc.push([item.Category, item.Count])
  return acc;
}, [
  ['Category', 'Count']
]);

console.log(newChartData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use, [**array.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and return the array of elements like, `[item.Category, item.Count]`.

And using [**array.unshift()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift), you can push the keys as the first value like, `data.unshift(["Category", "Count"])`.

If you have dynamic keys then you could also use,
`data.unshift(Object.keys(chartData.chartOne[0]))` .

Solution as follows:

```js
const chartData = {
  chartOne: [{
      Category: "cat1",
      Count: 11
    },
    {
      Category: "cat2",
      Count: 14
    },
    {
      Category: "cat3",
      Count: 21
    }
  ]
}

const data = chartData.chartOne.map(item => [item.Category, item.Count]);

data.unshift(Object.keys(chartData.chartOne[0]))

console.log(data)
```